# New Brunswick - Express Entry Labour Market Stream

Tags: canada, immigration

As per the official immigration [website](http://www.welcomenb.ca/content/wel-bien/en/immigrating_and_settling/how_to_immigrate/new_brunswick_provincialnomineeprogram/New_Brunswick_express_entry.html) of NB, It is informed that,

> The first step in applying to the NBPNP EELMS is to complete the Expression of Interest (EOI) form and email it to entree.express.entry@gnb.ca.  The NBPNP will receive EOI forms from the **1st to the 15th of each month**.  The NBPNP staff will score and rank the forms and invite the most suitable candidates to apply to the EELMS from the first of the following submission month.

This news is posted early this month.

My question:

Am I suppose to email my EOI form between 1st and 15th of next month(June)? Am I late for this month of May?

Comment: That certainly sounds correct. Limiting the dates each month for submittals means that there's a cut-off and they can then rank the available applications. It's backed up by the later statement that they may stop taking applications for a time or change the dates to ensure that all applications are handled properly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that was the process in the early days of the program. When first launched, and when your questions was posed, the NBPNP had a two-week time frame in which it accepted applications. Those were then reviewed promptly so that the selected candidates could apply in the following month. That system has been streamlined since it began early in 2015.

> The New Brunswick Provincial Nominee Program (NBPNP) has developed and launched its [Express Entry Labour Market Stream (EELMS)](http://www.welcomenb.ca/content/dam/wel-bien/pdf/ExpressEntryGuide-E.pdf). This stream allows the NBPNP to use [CIC’s Express Entry system](http://www.welcomenb.ca/content/dam/wel-bien/pdf/ExpressEntryGuide-E.pdf) to meet New Brunswick’s specific labour market and demographic needs.
>
> **Please visit our website often as the dates we accept EOI forms may change, depending on volume and priorities. The EELMS may be paused occasionally to ensure we can process applications and respect our nomination allocation**. Therefore, only a portion of potential candidates will be invited to apply. Please keep in mind that meeting the minimum Program requirements does not ensure you get an invitation to apply.
>
> [N]ominated individuals may receive an invitation to apply for permanent residency from Citizenship and Immigration Canada (CIC). For more details on this process, please visit the [CIC Express Entry website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/index.asp).